# How to change bullet color in OSX Notes

Tags: macos, colors, bullets, apple-notes

I'm trying to change the theme of my Notes app (to ultimate get green text on a black background).  I changed the background by changing the `paper.tiff` file in `Notes.app/Resources` to black, and changed the font color by simply doing it in the application, but I don't know how to change the bullet color.  All bullets are still black in the application.

Answer (score 0):

Add `color: #fff000;` or whatever color you want to the `li` tags in the `pad.css` file.